# JMOL pdb files not being served

Tags: java, iis, asp.net-mvc-2

I am building an asp.net mvc web site which needs to host some JMOL content.

JMOL is an open-source Java viewer for chemical structures in 3D.

http://jmol.sourceforge.net/

The problem is that when I host the JMOL files which have been created for this site on IIS, I get errors when JMOL attempts to load the .pdb files.

e.g. java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: ../amylase.pdb

Now my best guess is that because this is Microsoft and an ASP.NET/MVC site it's preventing the pdb files being served. Question is other than change the extension is there a way to fix this?

Comment: IIS 7.5 doesn't block pdb files being served. You would also get another response code if the request was blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out IIS didn't know how to serve the .pdb extension so I added a mime-type for it (using application/octet-stream as the mime type)